# Can I tell gradle that two different dependency modules are actually the same and make it pick the one with highest version?

Tags: java, gradle, jersey, glassfish, netflix-feign

I have a project depending on Netflix Feign and Glassfish Jersey implementation.

Feign uses the 1.1 spec of JAX-RS (JSR 311), and glassfish jersey implementation uses the 2.0 spec. The 2.0 is backward compatible, but **the Gradle dependency name is changed**.

Thus I have two dependencies in my project:

- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1
- javax.ws.rs:javax-ws-rs-api:2.0.1

Both implements the **same classes** in the **same packages**, but one according to 1.x and one according to 2.x

In my Java code, I can only point out the class name and the package.

Can I tell Gradle that this actually is the same package although the name differs and in that way only get one set of the implementing classes in the class path?

Right now it is random what version of the classes that the JVM and Compiler picks. Sometime it does not compile, sometimes it compiles but does not run (MethodNotFoundException).

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but you can explicitly exclude the old dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I added this to my gradle file and it looks alright:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api') with module('javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1')
    }
}
```

The dependency tree no longer includes the javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api dependency, and no more MethodNotFound-exception for javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties(...) method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is the best way, but it works:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
    all { DependencySubstitution d ->
      if (d.requested instanceof ModuleComponentSelector && d.requested.name == 'jsr311-api') {
        d.useTarget group: d.requested.group, name: 'javax-ws-rs-api', version: d.requested.version
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Updated:**

It's possible to do so another way using [nebula.resolution-rules](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.resolution-rules) plugin and such configuration:

*replace-jsr.json*

```
{
  "replace" : [
      {
        "module" : "javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api",
        "with" : "javax.ws.rs:javax-ws-rs-api",
        "reason" : "The JSR spec jar maven coordinates changed for 2.0 and later",
        "author" : "Andreas Lundgren",
        "date" : "2016-08-08T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
  ],
  "align": [],
  "substitute": [],
  "deny": [],
  "reject": []
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input! I didn't use it directly, the nebula is a bit overkill for me, but it definitely got me at the right track!